# Twitter import date malfunction

Tags: date-and-time, social-media

I am using the following procedure to analyze twitters, which was working correctly yesterday, but today I am facing some problems. Did Wolfram change something?

Thanks

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]
twitter["TweetSearch", "Query" -> "#falconheavy", MaxItems -> 25]
```

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? Looks like something went sideways with `DateObject`. On the other hand for me this works: `DateObject[{"2020 Mar 23 15:25:10", {"Year", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "Time"}},
 TimeZone -> 0]` and so I'm not sure what would be breaking. Try doing a `Quit`?

Comment: 12.0 I did, but no avail!

Comment: Try evaluating `DateObject[{"2020 Mar 23 15:25:10", {"Year", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "Time"}}, TimeZone -> 0]` if that's not working that you might need some form of `PacletUpdate` but I'm not sure which paclet

Comment: DateObject::str: String 2020 Mar 23 15:25:10 cannot be interpreted as a date.

Comment: That's a pretty fundamental issue. I'm not sure where it's coming from, to be honest. Maybe you can try `PacletUpdate["Interpreter"]` to see if it's using the `Interpreter` package under the hood?

Comment: Unfortunatly not succeeded also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was some kind of localisation issue here. I changed the language in the preferences to English and deactivated the "natural language detection". Now it works.

[image: screenshot attached]